# I can't sign my code. What will be the impact on end users?

Tags: java, macos, certificate, code-signing

I've been looking into using Jar Bundler to create a `.app` from my `.jar` and I read that you should sign the code using a Developer ID certificate before bundling the application. However, I am not a member of the Mac Developer Program and cannot afford to be for now.

So how will not signing the Java application change the end-users experience, if at all? How badly do I need to find an alternative solution, if available?

Comment: I believe you'll end up with warnings, and the user might have to right click it to run it. I recommend doing a google search of "mac run unsigned app" for more info.

Answer (score 0):

well unsigned java is worse than unsigned cocoa from a usability standpoint, because you don't have access to the file system.

if you have a native cocoa app bundle you get different security warnings and safeguards depending on the end user's settings, but with java I am pretty sure unsigned means basically no Disk or network IO

Comment: Oh that is not what I wanted to hear! I really can't afford $99 a year right now, so are there any alternative solutions for me to limit the impact of not having signed code? Also is this on all versions of osx?

Comment: to sign a jar you don't need a developer cert (but I am not a java expert), in fact I am not even certain that they are the same format... you can create your own fake cert in keychain.app or or purchase one from one of the places that java folks usually do (verisign, thawte, etc.) although I just checked thawte and they are 3 times as much as an ADC Mac Developer membership

Comment: Also If you are just running this on your own machine, or an organizations machines, you can just make your own CA and then from that make a code signing cert... and If you mean your code for any sort of public use, then you should be able to come up with US$100

Comment: @GradyPlayer Unsigned java apps can see the file system, so long as the OS allows them to run (i.e., the "Anywhere" security option is selected).  I think you are thinking of Java _applets_.

Comment: @whiskeyspider that may be... It has been a long time since I have played with java (8 years?), but I remember that being an issue at that time; but I am by no means an expert on JVM

Comment: @GradyPlayer Yeah, I noticed that Apple would be a cheaper option, and yes, my application is for public use. However, I'm only a solo-developer and I'm already in debt. I can consider it once I start making sales, but I think I will just have to educate users in the mean time unfortunately, so long as unsigned apps can access the disk.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on their Security preferences.  If a user has their "Allow applications downloaded from" security preference set to "Mac App Store and identified developers", then by default they will not be able to run your app (but see options below).  This restriction has nothing to do with Java and would apply similarly to an unsigned Cocoa app.

If they changed the setting to "Anywhere", then they'd be able to run your app.

Another option is to tell your users to Control-click or right-click the app, then select Open.  This will give them the option to bypass the default security setting for this app only.  Once they run it, they won't get the warnings again.

Certainly the smoothest route is to sign your app, but I don't think unsigned apps are so uncommon either and you may find that many of your users are already educated to this procedure.

Comment: I suspected this may be the case - I assume that by default the OS doesn't allow applications to be run from "Anywhere" also. If there are no alternative solutions, I guess the next question would be how is best to inform Mac users that the app is unsigned? Also, how strongly do Mac users tend to react to unsigned code?

Comment: I would add a note of explanation next to the download link, perhaps even with instructions on how to control-click, etc.  Personally, if the website I download it from doesn't raise any red flags, I'd probably be comfortable enough to try it out.  My guess is your app won't be the first unsigned your users have encountered.